# Dynamic visualforce component for apex repeat

Tags: dynamic-vf-component

**VF**

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!DynamicPicklist}"/>
```

**Apex**

```
public List<MyWrapperClass> lstPicklistValues{get;set;}
public Component.Apex.repeat getDynamicPicklist() {
        Component.Apex.repeat myDetailList= new Component.Apex.repeat(var='l');
        myDetailList.expressions.value = '{!lstPicklistValues}';

        Component.Apex.OutputLabel theLevelLabel = new Component.Apex.OutputLabel();
        theLevelLabel.value = '{!l.level.Value__c}';

        myDetailList.childComponents.add(theLevelLabel);

        return myDetailList;
    }
```

The above code displays as below,

> {!l.level.Value__c} {!l.level.Value__c} {!l.level.Value__c}
>   {!l.level.Value__c} {!l.level.Value__c}

Its not fetching value instead its hardcoded with `'{!l.level.Value__c}'`

please help! i am stuck with this since long time

Comment: hi @KeithC can you solve this issue?

Comment: When Apex code such as your `getDynamicPicklist` method executes there is no `{!}` substitution mechanism or context available: that is only available in a Visualforce page or component. I suggest looking for a non-dynamic component solution; if you can't find one your can post another question that explains what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: that means dynamic component doesnt work with apex repeat. i feel like there has to be some way. because i didnt find apex:repeat in dynamicComponent not supported list.

Comment: Also i tried it by referring this https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm

Comment: I've found dynamic components to be too flawed to use. For example, when there are input fields and a validation error occurs the current values are lost because dynamic components can't be serialized into the view state.

Answer (score -2):

`theLevelLabel.expressions.value = '{!l.level.Value__c}';`

Comment: Bryan, you'd clear up your answer if you also explain it.